# Submit app with a Apple Development Certificate for Push notifications or Production Certificate?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, app-store

I am about to submit my app and not sure what I should do about the certificates used for the push notifications. I am using Parse.com for my backend. Do I need to update the certificate for the database to production for when Apple review the app or do I leave it as development and do it after release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit it with Development Certificate.
And When Your App Is Approved then Update it to Production Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires you to have your backend set up production ready for review, otherwise your app is likely to be rejected.

[See dot 2.9](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/%23functionality)